# Unity - How to get date format of device on Android?

Tags: c#, android, date, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the date format of the device in my game. I changed my date format to month/day/year in the device's settings and the code down below gave me "MM/dd/yyyy" in the log. Then I changed my date format to day/month/year but still the log was "MM/dd/yyyy".

How can I get the date format in Android?

I'm using a class in the System.Globalization library

```
Debug.Log(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern)
```

I also tried to restart the device after changing the date format in the settings, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern` are just format string.

Try

```
 Debug.Log(System.DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern));
```

Comment: The problem is I want to get the format not the date. In your code shortdatepattern will still return "MM/dd/yyyy". I changed my settings to "dd/MM/yyyy", however, I can't get that format on Android. It always returns "MM/dd/yyyy". It looks like DateFormatInfo can't reach the date format of the device. I'm looking for an alternative way to get the date format.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try.

```
String DateString = system.datetime.now.tostring;

String[] BreakUp1 = DateString.split(',');

String[] BreakUp2 = BreakUp1.split('/');

String newDate = BreakUp[1] + "/" + BreakUp[0] + "/" + BreakUp[2];
```

This will create dd/mm/yyyy if the format is originally coming out mm/dd/yyyy.